# Erroneous INSERT in MySQL from Java application

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

Good day!  I am hoping that someone might be able to point me in the correct direction, or be able to point out what
I might be doing incorrectly.

I am fairly new to working with Java and MySQL; more specifically, database manipulation in MySQL from Java.

I wrote the attached prototype in Java to solve the following problem:

Given a table 'mailing':

```
    CREATE TABLE `mailing` (
        ind INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
        `addr` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY (ind)
    );
```

The mailing table will initially be empty.  New addresses will be added on a daily basis.  It is expected that the table will store at least 10,000,000 email addresses and 100,000 domains.

Write a program that updates another table which holds a daily count of email addresses by their domain name.

Use this table to report the top 50 domains by count sorted by percentage growth of the last 30 days compared to the total.

** NOTE **

- The original mailing table should not be modified.

I pretty much have a solution, but my solution is producing an unexpected result which I can not explain.  In point form, here is what I am doing:

- Create a TempResult table if one does not exist.  The TempResult table is identical in form to the original 'mailing' table shown above.
- Next, I perform a query on 'mailing' and 'TempResult' by doing a set difference, inserting the difference found in 'mailing' into 
  'TempResult'.
- I then perform a query on 'TempResult', parse each email addres extracting the domain, and insert the result into an arraylist.
- After parsing is complete, I insert each unique element into a hash map, and increment the value attribute, thus counting occurences.
- The next step is to iterate over the hash map, and insert each mapping into the 'Result' table in the database.  The result table format is as follows and created only if it did not previously exist.

  ```
  CREATE TABLE `Result` (
      ind INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `domain` VARCHAR(255),
      dailyCount INT,
      theDate DATE,
      primary key (ind)
  );
  ```
- Lastly I perform a query to produce the final output desired.

Here is my problem.  When I run this program with sample data, and both 'TempResult' and 'Result' do not exist, the program executes properly, and I get output data that I expect.  However, when I run it again with the same data, my 'Result' table is showing duplicate records, and erroneous counts.  I have narrowed down the problem to the bock of code when I do the INSERT INTO 'Result', but I can't see what I did wrong.  Can someone point out to me where I went wrong?

Thank you in advance.....and forgive me if this is a rookie mistake.

Mike

```
    import java.sql.Connection;
    import java.sql.DriverManager;
    import java.sql.SQLException;
    import java.sql.*;
    import java.time.*;
    import java.util.*;


    public class Test 
    {
        public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
        {
        String ConnectionURL = "jdbc:mysql://www.xxxxxxxx.ca:3306/Emails?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false";
        String user = "xxxxxxxxxxxx";
        String password = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
        String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
        Connection conn = null;
        List<String> addresses = new ArrayList<String>();

        //establish connection to DB
        try 
        {
            // The newInstance() call is a work around for some
            // broken Java implementations
            Class.forName(driver).newInstance();
        } 
        catch (Exception ex) 
        {
            // handle the error
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        }

        //connect to DB and perform queries
        try 
        {
            //get  connection to the database 'Emails'
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(ConnectionURL, user, password);
            conn.setAutoCommit(false);

            //check to see if TempResult Table exists.
            DatabaseMetaData metaOne = conn.getMetaData();
            ResultSet metaDataOne = metaOne.getTables(null, null, "TempResult", null);

            //Create temporary result table TempResult if not exists
            if (!metaDataOne.next())
            {
                String queryOne = "CREATE TABLE TempResult (ind INT AUTO_INCREMENT, addr VARCHAR(255), PRIMARY KEY ( ind ))";
                PreparedStatement statementOne = conn.prepareStatement(queryOne);
                statementOne.executeUpdate();
                conn.commit();
            }


            //Insert set difference between mailing and TempResult into TempResult
            String queryTwo = "INSERT INTO TempResult (SELECT * FROM mailing e WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM TempResult t WHERE e.ind = t.ind))";
            PreparedStatement statementTwo = conn.prepareStatement(queryTwo);
            statementTwo.executeUpdate();
            conn.commit();


            //now read into memory table TempResult into an arraylist
            //parse each email to obtain the domain of each email only  
            Statement queryThree = conn.createStatement();
            ResultSet result = queryThree.executeQuery("SELECT addr FROM TempResult");
            while (result.next())
            {
                String delimiter = "[@]";
                String elements[] = result.getString("addr").split(delimiter);      
                addresses.add(elements[1]);
                //System.out.println(result.getString("addr"));
            }
            queryThree.close();
            result.close();


            //now map the arraylist to a HashMap to create a 'dictionary' with counts on the domains.
            int occurance;
            int temp;
            HashMap<String, Integer> domains = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
            for (String a : addresses)
            {
                if(domains.containsKey(a))
                {
                    temp = domains.get(a);
                    occurance = temp + 1;
                    domains.replace(a, occurance);
                }
                else
                {
                    occurance = 1;
                    domains.put(a, occurance);
                }
            }


            /* //for testing only
            for (HashMap.Entry<String, Integer> entry : domains.entrySet())
            {
                System.out.println(entry.getKey() + " " + entry.getValue());
            } */


            //check to see if Result Table exists.
            DatabaseMetaData metaTwo = conn.getMetaData();  
            ResultSet metaDataTwo = metaTwo.getTables(null, null, "Result", null);

            //Create Result table if not exists
            if (!metaDataTwo.next())
            {
                String queryFour = "CREATE TABLE Result (ind INT AUTO_INCREMENT, domain VARCHAR(255), dailyCount INT, theDate DATE, PRIMARY KEY ( ind ))";
                PreparedStatement statementFour = conn.prepareStatement(queryFour);
                statementFour.executeUpdate();
                conn.commit();
            }


            //insert hashmap into Result table.
            String queryFive = "INSERT INTO Result (ind, domain, dailyCount, theDate) VALUES (NULL, ?, ?, CURDATE())";
            PreparedStatement statementFive = conn.prepareStatement(queryFive);
            for (HashMap.Entry<String, Integer> entry : domains.entrySet())
            {
                statementFive.setString(1, entry.getKey());
                statementFive.setInt(2, entry.getValue());
                statementFive.executeUpdate();
                conn.commit();
            }


            //Read Result table into memory and display to system console
            Statement display = conn.createStatement();
            String query = "SELECT domain, " +
                " dailyCount / " +
                " (SELECT " +
                " SUM(dailyCount) " +
                " FROM Result) " +
                " * 100 " +
                " AS PercentGrowth " +
                " FROM Result " +
                " WHERE theDate " +
                " > DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), " +
                " INTERVAL 1 MONTH) " +
                " ORDER BY PercentGrowth " +
                " DESC LIMIT 50 ";
            ResultSet finalResult = display.executeQuery(query);
            while (finalResult.next())
            {
                System.out.println(finalResult.getString("domain") + " " + finalResult.getString("PercentGrowth"));
            }
            finalResult.close();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
        finally
        {
            //close the connection to the database
            conn.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to delete the table if it exists.

Comment: Jay,  Thanks.  I however need to add to the Result table daily, and I use the TempResult Table to determine what new entries are placed into 'mailing' by performing an equivalent to MINUS on these two.

Comment: ok wait so you are putting these entries into TempResult and then putting them into Result? Duplicate Entry would just be on the ID, so take what you have from TempResult and insert into Result, and if you do it without the "ID" column if you have Result set to auto increment, it should just give itself its own ID.

Comment: Actually, I think I know where the problem is now....silly me.  I think I need to add an additional table for the set difference, which I do delete when done with....I will play with this later to confirm my findings.

Answer (score 0):

I found my main error.  I needed to create an additional temp table to save the set difference, import this into a hash map, and then drop tis table when done.  My issue is resolved.  I just need to fix my final query.

Here is the updated code.   **Excuse the formatting***

```
    import java.sql.Connection;
    import java.sql.DriverManager;
    import java.sql.SQLException;
    import java.sql.*;
    import java.time.*;
    import java.util.*;


    public class Test 
    {
        public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
        {
            String ConnectionURL = "jdbc:mysql://www.xxxxxxxxx:3306/Emails?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false";
            String user = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
    String password = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
    String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
    Connection conn = null;
    List<String> addresses = new ArrayList<String>();

    //establish connection to DB
    try 
    {
        // The newInstance() call is a work around for some
        // broken Java implementations
        Class.forName(driver).newInstance();
    } 
    catch (Exception ex) 
    {
        // handle the error
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
    }

    //connect to DB and perform queries
    try 
    {
        //get  connection to the database 'Emails'
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(ConnectionURL, user, password);
        conn.setAutoCommit(false);

        //check to see if TempResult Table exists.
        DatabaseMetaData metaOne = conn.getMetaData();
        ResultSet metaDataOne = metaOne.getTables(null, null, "TempResult", null);

        //Create temporary result table TempResult if not exists
        if (!metaDataOne.next())
        {
            String queryOne = "CREATE TABLE TempResult (ind INT AUTO_INCREMENT, addr VARCHAR(255), PRIMARY KEY ( ind ))";
            PreparedStatement statementOne = conn.prepareStatement(queryOne);
            statementOne.executeUpdate();
            conn.commit();
        }


        //create another temporary table for the differences only which will be dropped when process
        //is complete.
        String tempQueryOne = "CREATE TABLE Temp (ind INT AUTO_INCREMENT, addr VARCHAR(255), PRIMARY KEY ( ind ))";
        PreparedStatement queryStmtOne = conn.prepareStatement(tempQueryOne);
        queryStmtOne.executeUpdate();
        conn.commit();

        String tempQueryTwo = "INSERT INTO Temp (SELECT * FROM mailing e WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM TempResult t WHERE e.ind = t.ind))";
        PreparedStatement queryStmtTwo = conn.prepareStatement(tempQueryTwo);
        queryStmtTwo.executeUpdate();
        conn.commit();

        //Insert set difference between mailing and TempResult into TempResult
        String queryTwo = "INSERT INTO TempResult (SELECT * FROM mailing e WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM TempResult t WHERE e.ind = t.ind))";
        PreparedStatement statementTwo = conn.prepareStatement(queryTwo);
        statementTwo.executeUpdate();
        conn.commit();


        //now read into memory table TempResult into an arraylist
        //parse each email to obtain the domain of each email only  
        Statement queryThree = conn.createStatement();
        ResultSet result = queryThree.executeQuery("SELECT addr FROM Temp");
        while (result.next())
        {
            String delimiter = "[@]";
            String elements[] = result.getString("addr").split(delimiter);      
            addresses.add(elements[1]);
            //System.out.println(result.getString("addr"));
        }
        queryThree.close();
        result.close();


        //now map the arraylist to a HashMap to create a 'dictionary' with counts on the domains.
        int occurance;
        int temp;
        HashMap<String, Integer> domains = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
        for (String a : addresses)
        {
            if(domains.containsKey(a))
            {
                temp = domains.get(a);
                occurance = temp + 1;
                domains.replace(a, occurance);
            }
            else
            {
                occurance = 1;
                domains.put(a, occurance);
            }
        }


        //for testing only
        for (HashMap.Entry<String, Integer> entry : domains.entrySet())
        {
            System.out.println(entry.getKey() + " " + entry.getValue());
        }


        //check to see if Result Table exists.
        DatabaseMetaData metaTwo = conn.getMetaData();  
        ResultSet metaDataTwo = metaTwo.getTables(null, null, "Result", null);

        //Create Result table if not exists
        if (!metaDataTwo.next())
        {
            String queryFour = "CREATE TABLE Result (ind INT AUTO_INCREMENT, domain VARCHAR(255), dailyCount INT, theDate DATE, PRIMARY KEY ( ind ))";
            PreparedStatement statementFour = conn.prepareStatement(queryFour);
            statementFour.executeUpdate();
            conn.commit();
        }


        //insert hashmap into Result table.
        String queryFive = "INSERT INTO Result (ind, domain, dailyCount, theDate) VALUES (NULL, ?, ?, CURDATE())";
        PreparedStatement statementFive = conn.prepareStatement(queryFive);
        for (HashMap.Entry<String, Integer> entry : domains.entrySet())
        {
            statementFive.setString(1, entry.getKey());
            statementFive.setInt(2, entry.getValue());
            statementFive.executeUpdate();
            conn.commit();
        }


        //Read Reult table into memory and display to system console
        Statement display = conn.createStatement();
        String query = "SELECT domain, " +
            " dailyCount / " +
            " (SELECT " +
            " SUM(dailyCount) " +
            " FROM Result) " +
            " * 100 " +
            " AS PercentGrowth " +
            " FROM Result " +
            " WHERE theDate " +
            " > DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), " +
            " INTERVAL 1 MONTH) " +
            " ORDER BY PercentGrowth " +
            " DESC LIMIT 50 ";
        ResultSet finalResult = display.executeQuery(query);
        while (finalResult.next())
        {
            System.out.println(finalResult.getString("domain") + " " + finalResult.getString("PercentGrowth"));
        }
        finalResult.close();


        //clean up and drop table 'Temp'
        String tempQueryThree = "DROP TABLE Temp";
        PreparedStatement queryStmtThree = conn.prepareStatement(tempQueryThree);
        queryStmtThree.executeUpdate();
        conn.commit();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
    finally
    {
        //close the connection to the database
        conn.close();
            }
        }
    }
```